# in c++ mean median mode program the median and mode sections do not work

Tags: c++, mean, median, mode

I wrote the following **program** with **c++**

https://dl.smartnima.com/cpp.cpp

But the **median** and **mode** sections do not work
please direct me.

mode program :

```
void  mode(int a[], int len )
{
int f[len]={0};            
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
   ++f[a[i]];
// f[0]=1 ,f[1]=5,f[2]= 1, ... ,f[9]=1


int max=f[0];
int index=0;
for(int j=1;j<=9;j++)
{
   if (f[j]> max)
      {
         max=f[j];
         index=j;
      }
}

// max =5  , index =1
int mode=a[f[index]];
cout<<"\n mode: "<<mode;
cout<<endl<<"\n index: "<<f[mode]<<endl;
    
}
```

mean program:

```
void mean( const int x[], int len )
{
 int sum = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
  sum += x[ i ];

  cout << fixed << setprecision( 4);

  cout << " \n \n mean =" <<    static_cast< double > (sum) / len  << "\n";

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please show us your [mcve] *inside the question itself*.

Comment: `int f[len]={0};` is not valid C++, it is a compiler-specific extension that C++ students should not be using. Worse still, `++f[a[i]];` will break horribly if any number in your array is less than 0 or larger than `len`. OTOH if you know your numbers are between 0 and 9, why `int f[len]` and not `int f[10]`, which is perfectly valid C++?

Comment: [Mean](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mean/), [median](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median/) and [mode](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mode/) C++ codes by geeksforgeeks, try to see if that helps.